# how i can show and hide button in click on spinner android

Tags: java, android

i have spinner  and 3 item  video  and photo  and text  and 4 button   how i can show  button  if  spinner select :

0
dow
favorite

Im trying to show a hidden button  with spinner click

this is the cod

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_secim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rdvanayan.yeni.Secim"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">


    <TextView
        android:text="Bir seçim yapınız"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="KAYDET"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/kad1"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        />

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/kad1"
    android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">




        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/camera1"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="78dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:visibility="invisible"


                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera" />

            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="111dp"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/galll"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:text="URL İNDİR "
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton9"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="78dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
                    android:onClick="dispatchTakeVideoIntent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/video_kamera" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="111dp"
                    android:layout_height="78dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/video_galeri"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:text="URL İNDİR "
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton9"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:hint="BAŞLIK"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:hint="AÇIKLAMA"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#ffffff"

        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/igm"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/son"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is spinner item

```html
 <string-array name="secim">
        <item> YAZI </item>
        <item> RESİM </item>
        <item> VİDEO </item>
    </string-array>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show and hide buttons on spinner selection in your Activity class. Set "OnItemSelectedListener" to your spinner, it will override few methods. In overridden "OnItemSelected" method hide the button like this:

```
yourButton.setVisibility(VISIBILTY.GONE);
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.secim, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: After this code add "spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()".

Comment: //spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          //  @Override
         //   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //       camerax.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         //   }
      //  });

Comment: Did it work for you? if not then problem is you have to use "OnItemSelcetedListener" not "OnItemClickListener".

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the previous answer as a comment. But the reputation is inadequate.

Actually it should be like this:

Use for hide: `resimButonu.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
or `resimButonu.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);`

use for show: `resimButonu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` or `resimButonu.setVisibility(VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

thanks but i have 4 button and text  i need :
if  *RESİM*  selected    show  2 button 
if   * YAZI *  selected   show   textbox 
if   *VİDEO *  selected    show   2 button
 i have 4 button in app

```html
 ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.secim, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
         spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 camerax.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }

             @Override
             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


             }
```